# What's the relation between Session and SMTP Connection in javamail?

Tags: session, smtp, connection, jakarta-mail, transport

In my email-send-app, I holding a Singleton Session instance in SenderImpl. 
For per email message i retrieve Transport instance from session for sending, and close it after sending is complete.

Now i want reuse SMTP Connection for batch emails sending, so i want figure out, what is the relation between Session, Transport and underlying Socket Connection(SMTP Connection)?

A Transport instance Corresponds to a single underlying Socket Connection, is that correct?

No correlation between Session and underlying Socket Connection, is that right?

All response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Transport corresponds to a single connection.

A Session holds configuration information.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bill.

Another two questions:

Comment: our Email App is in China and SMTP Server is in Europe(a commercial SMTP provider), the Socket Connection is so expensive, on an average it taking around 5 seconds to open it(the actually sending just taking around 2 seconds), for better performance, i must reuse it.
i want let Transport instance as instance variable(or static variable?) of SenderImpl. Open it when app start. 
1 As instance variable, Transport instance is threadsafe or not? 
2 How can i ensure that the underlying Socket Connection can be close after a period time idle(ie, half hour), and reopen it when a new message is coming?

Comment: A lot of questions in there...  A Transport instance is thread safe, but you can't usefully use it from more than one thread because it manages access to a single connection that can only be used by one thread at a time.  The server will close the connection when it decides you haven't used it recently enough.  You can use the isConnected method to see if it's open before you use it, but note that it can still be closed by the server between when you check and when you use it.  The server would greatly prefer that you close the connection when you're not actively using it.